# Finding multiple min/max using Collections.min/max

Tags: java, collections, min

In an example I was working on, I was trying to find the smallest three elements in a list (without sorting the list) and then add those three elements into a new list.

Because it was an example I could just simple use a for loop, use `Collections.min(list)` add that element to the new list, then remove that element from the original list. If I had not removed the element, I would get the same element three times. However, by removing the element, I got my desired outcome.

How can I do this without removing the max/min elements from the list?

Comment: Why can not you sort the list? Can we assume that you want to keep whole or real natural numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the max/min 3 elements, I would suggest you to use a `PriorityQueue`:

`PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(k);`

And then in a loop, add elements to this queue.

And then you can add these 3 elements to the list by removing from the queue and simply return from the method.

Even better would be to use 3 seperate variables and directly loop on the main list. **Note:** this method will not be feasible if you later on update 3 to some other value. Whereas `PriorityQueue` approach will be flexible.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    Integer arr[] = {2, 6, 5, 3, 7, 9, 12, 35, 1, 3};
    List<Integer> incoming = Arrays.asList(arr);
    Comparator<Integer> maxFirstComparator = (x, y) -> Integer.compare(y,x);
    printList(getMinOrMaxKNumbers(incoming, 3, null));
    System.out.println();
    printList(getMinOrMaxKNumbers(incoming, 3, maxFirstComparator));
}

/*
 * gets the max/min K elements from the List
 * @param comparator    if null is passed the method uses natural ordering
 *
 */
private static List<Integer> getMinOrMaxKNumbers(List<Integer> incoming, int k, Comparator<Integer> comparator) {
    int n = incoming.size();
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = comparator == null ? new PriorityQueue<>(n) : new PriorityQueue<>(n, comparator);

    for (int i : incoming) {
        pq.add(i);
    }

    List<Integer> outgoing = new ArrayList<>(k);
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        outgoing.add(pq.poll());
    }

    return outgoing;
}

private static void printList(List<Integer> list) {
    list.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.print(x + " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any straight forward way to do this using the standard library.

The following code contains a utility method to get the set of a number of maximal elements.

It works by keeping the maximal elements in a `TreeSet`, to which an element is inserted only if it belongs to the maximal elements. A tree set is a good fit here because it is fast to find the minimal element, and to test if an element is contained in the set.

In this way you get good performance, and can be flexible with the number of maximal elements you want.

```
public class MultipleMaxElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l = List.of(4, 2, 5, 8, 2, 8, 0, 1);

        System.out.println(maxElements(l, 3, Comparator.naturalOrder()));
        System.out.println(maxElements(l, 3, Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder().reversed()));
    }

    public static <T> Set<T> maxElements(Iterable<T> list, int nrElems, Comparator<T> cmp) {
        TreeSet<T> maxSet = new TreeSet<>(cmp);

        for (T elem : list) {
            if (maxSet.size() < nrElems) {
                maxSet.add(elem);
            } else if (!maxSet.contains(elem) && cmp.compare(elem, maxSet.first()) > 0) {
                maxSet.pollFirst();
                maxSet.add(elem);               
            }
        }

        return maxSet;
    }
}
```

In the question text you don't write anything about how duplicate elements in the input list should be handled. This method returns maximal unique elements.

If duplicates should be preserved then a tree based Guava multi-set could be used instead of a normal `TreeSet`.